# What did Geordi mean when he said "And then some" ("Sins of the Father")?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the episode "Sins of the Father", Riker says that Kurn has the crew on his toes. I get that. But then Geordi says "And then some" which is obviously a response, but is that supposed to be an insult to Kurn?

Comment: Voting to leave open because [meaning of phrases in a SFF work is on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11626/98028). @HorusKol

Comment: @Jenayah Fair 'nuff

Answer (score 8):

> KURN: I find the constraints a bit difficult to conform to. Just a short while ago, I had to stop myself from killing Commander Riker. I believe he was trying to communicate the crew's sense of discomfort with my style of command. Under different circumstances, I would consider that a challenge to my authority.
>   PICARD: One of the aims of the exchange programme, Commander, is for all of us to learn tolerance. As for my crew, it may be healthy to shake up the status quo occasionally.
>   RIKER: The Commander certainly appears to have the crew on its toes
>   LAFORGE: And then some. No offence, sir.

"And then some" as an English phrase simply means "that and more" with an implication that it's too much.  Geordi is insinuating that Kurn's style of command not only had the crew ready, but also anxious, which is not necessarily a good thing. In this case, the death threats are part of what is putting people over the edge.

Comment: The 'no offense' part can be interpreted as being for the benefit of Riker. Picard effectively just said "This Kurn guy may be making some necessary changes to get things ship shape around here", to which Riker (who's job it is to keep things ship shape) says "yes...he does seem to be effective", to which LaForge ostensibly agrees. LaForge saying "No offense" to Riker is to let Riker know that Geordi is *not* saying Kurn is doing better than Riker. As FuzzyBoots said, the crew is beyond mere preparedness into abject nervosa

Comment: Indeed. It's "Holy crap, this guy has everybody _well_ in discipline right now. I've never seen anything like it. Very effective. Er, no offence boss sorry you're great too actually I like you more because we all kind of hate it right now"

Comment: If you watch the scene, the "no offence" is directed at Kurn, not Riker, as they are all at the dinner table.